# command button (Active X control) in VBA is not stable in one location

Tags: excel, vba

I'm facing a new problem in vba. I have create a active X button in excel vba, named "transfer". It contains the below code

```
Option Explicit

Dim msg, clear_content As String

Private Sub Transfer_data_Click()

    If Sheets("Print").Range("B8") = "" Then
        
        Sheets("final").Range("B8:D39").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Print").Range("B8")
          
          
    ElseIf Sheets("Print").Range("B59") = "" Then
        
        Sheets("final").Range("B8:D39").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Print").Range("B59")
        
 
    Else

     msg = MsgBox("Print page is full,Do you need to clear the page", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "User Repsonse")

        If msg = vbYes Then
            
            clear_content = MsgBox("Warning! Print data will be erased completly", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "user response")
        
            If clear_content = vbYes Then
            
                Sheets("Print").Range("B8:J39").ClearContents
                Sheets("Print").Range("C44:J50").ClearContents
                
                Sheets("Print").Range("B59:J90").ClearContents
                Sheets("Print").Range("c95:J101").ClearContents
                
                
            End If
         
        End If
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

There are total 6 sheets, where 4 sheets contains data and in 5th sheet this "transfer" button is there. When i run the main program ,which will paste the result in this 5th page, this transfer button is placing randomly when my main code runs.
[before code run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqarC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqarC.png)

[Aftercode run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY4a8.png)]

Comment: Are you saying that the button moves when you press it or does it happen when you run the main program? If the main program is responsible, then I suspect that you are deleting some columns at some point in the code.

Comment: No i didn't delete any columns from the main program. If you refer both the images,you may get clarified

Comment: But you confirm that the button move after running the main program?

Comment: yes it moves after my main program over

Comment: It's really hard to know without the code of your main program, but my guess is that if you don't delete any columns, you're probably at least deleting cells.

Comment: Your screenshots clearly show that at least the range `H8:J24` (possibly further down) got deleted (see the missing borders) which made the command button move to the left. If you don't want the command button to move, right-click it and select *Format Control* and in the *Properties* tab select the radio button *Don't move or size with cells* and select *OK*.

Comment: @DecimalTurn sharing the code is not problem but it's a big program , contains around 500 lines of code. There is only one delete statment " sheets(" final").Range(" BI:D32"). There is not other delete statement in that program

Comment: @VBasic2008 thank you. It worked but still the columns are getting deleted

Comment: The deletion has nothing to do with the code you posted. In the main program, replace the only occurrence of `.Delete` with `.ClearContents`.